# Special function for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

Can the integrals of the following types be written in terms of any Special functions?

$$\int_0^\infty e^{\pm\alpha t}t^{\pm \beta t}\mathrm{d}t \quad\quad \{\alpha,\beta\}\in \mathbb{C}$$

All I have tried so far is tried to integrate numerically. I see that the plot of $e^x x^{-x}$ rapidly decreases so that the integral converges nicely. So, I am wondering if there are some functions in terms of which $\int_0^\infty e^x x^{-x}\mathrm{d}x$ can be written and whether the more general integral $\int_0^\infty e^{\pm\alpha t}t^{\pm \beta t}\mathrm{d}t \quad\quad \{\alpha,\beta\}\in \mathbb{C}$ can be written in terms of such functions for the region where integral converges.

Comment: A simplest case:$\int x^x\text{d}x$.This is called *Sophomore's dream*.And we have some indefinite integrals:$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}e^{-x}\Gamma(x)\sin(\pi x)
\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.However,the standard special functions can't express your integral(maybe).You can define a new function for it.